# Getting Errors why trying to update yii2 to a newer version

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to update yii2 to a newer version using composer, and i just updated my composer to latest version and after i run `composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.49" --update-with-dependencies` i got the below error

```
Problem 1
    - codeception/module-yii2 is locked to version 1.1.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - codeception/module-yii2 1.1.5 requires php >=5.6.0 <=8.1 | ~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.2.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/browser-kit is locked to version v4.2.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/browser-kit v4.2.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - sizeg/yii2-jwt v2.0.2 requires lcobucci/jwt ~3.3.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.3].
    - sizeg/yii2-jwt is locked to version v2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

i've being struggling now for few hours and i also try to run `composer update` but i got errors as well. how can i update the codeception/module-yii2? and also upgrade my yii2 version? thanks in advance to any help

Comment: According to a few resources I have read, yii is not ready for PHP 8.2 as of yet: [Current version of Yii 2 not ready for PHP 8.2?](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/current-version-of-yii-2-not-ready-for-php-8-2/135156) -- So you may have to revert to PHP 8.1 until it is ready ..

Comment: @Zak that's right, thanks for the heads up, i will try revert my php version

Comment: @Zak the post you've linked is from April 2023. The php 8.2 support has been added in version 2.0.48 released in May 2023. [See changelog](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.49/framework/CHANGELOG.md#2048-may-22-2023)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in package `sizeg/yii2-jwt`.

It's latest release requires `lcobucci/jwt: ~3.3.0`. But that package even in 3.4.x version doesn't support php 8.

You have 3 options:

**1. Run your app on php 7.4**

Yii 2.0.49 does support php 7.4 so composer update should be fine on that php version.

**2. You can force composer to install packages for php 7.4 while running app on php 8.2**

You will have to hope that everything will work fine.
You can do it by setting target platform in composer.json like this:

```
{
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.4.33"
    }
  }
}
```

If you do this the composer will ignore the current php version and instead install packages as if it was running on specified php version.
This is probably bad idea especially if your production environment runs php 8.2 too. It might be ok if your production environment runs php 7.4 but you don't want to install old php in your dev environment.

**3. You can give up on `sizeg/yii2-jwt` and use newer version of `lcobucci/jwt` directly**

In that case you will simply need to update the other two packages mentioned in composer output (`codeception/module-yii2` and `symfony/browser-kit`) to version that supports php 8.2. Running `composer update` after replacing the outdated `sizeg/yii2-jwt` requirement with latest `lcobucci/jwt` requirement should take care of updating them.

**NOTE**

You can always use `--dry-run` option with `composer` commands if you want to check what is going to happen. Using that option will make composer output the changes that would be done without actually doing any changes to installed packages.

Comment: Good answer. Respect